# discord.py command() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'

Tags: python, discord.py

So i am trying to make slash ban command in discord.py and i get this error:
`command() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'`

My code:

```py
@tree.command(name="ban", description="Ban someone", options = [app_commands.choices(name="user", description="select user to ban", option_type=6, required=True)])
async def _ban(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await user.ban(reason="NO reason")
    await ctx.send(f'Banned {user}! Reason: {reason}')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@tree.command(name="ban", description="Ban someone")
async def _ban(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await user.ban(reason="NO reason")
    await ctx.send(f'Banned {user}! Reason: {reason}')
```

If you are only using discord.py, which i assume so, `user: discord.Member` is enough. `options = [app_commands.choices(` isn't a thing.

[Read the docs on @discord.app_commands.CommandTree.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?%20command#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.command)

The real use of app_commands.choices looks like this:

```
@tree.command(name='command')
@app_commands.choices(option=[
  app_commands.Choice(name='option1', value='1'),
  app_commands.Choice(name='option2', value='2'),
])
async def command(interaction: discord.Interaction, option: app_commands.Choice[str]):
    if option.value == '1':
        #chosen option was option1
    elif option.value == '2':
        #chosen option was option2
```